# What can I do about my Pugs itchy red ears?

Tags: dogs

My pug is one year old and for the past year he has been getting itchy ears every once in a while. When I look into his ears they are red and sometimes hurt from all the scratching that he does. Is this normal? What can I do to get rid of this and prevent it from coming back?

Comment: Ask vet what's causing the itching. Could be allergy,  could be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every dog I know periodically has this problem. Typically one goes to the pet store and buys a Dog Ear Cleaning Solution. You squirt the liquid onto the ear, keep it in the ear canal, and massage the liquid as long as the bottle says. You can even hear it if you listen carefully. The redness should start to fade dramatically within 24 hours and after cleaning, the dog tends not to itch nearly as much.

There are also lotions that you can buy for allergy relief, but you'd need to check if it's okay for ears.

The issue is related to allergies, so the long-term solution probably involves a vet trip and investigating your home and considering different types of food. For example, when I don't vacuum regularly, the dog's allergies flare up, and I was able to cut down on allergies by switching to a different type of food.

Comment: When doing ears, it's tough to manage the ear solution bottle, the dog, and the ear itself all at the same time, so I like to have my dog put it's head on my knee while I massage, to help enforce the idea it should stay still. Whatever works for you.

Comment: Food allergies usually show up as inflammation in the ears or feet.